# Configuring an Interceptor in EJB3.2 deployment descriptor

Tags: java, xml, interceptor, java-ee-7, ejb-3.2

I would like to configure an `Interceptor` only in one Maven profile, so the obvious solution would be replacing the current annotation-based interceptor binding with a deployment descriptor based solution. However I cannot get this to work. Let's suppose, I have a bean:

```java
// @MyInterceptor
@Stateless
public class MyBean {
    // ...
}
```

And I have a corresponding `ejb-jar.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ejb-jar>
    <assembly-descriptor>
        <interceptor-binding>
            <ejb-name>MyBean</ejb-name>
            <interceptor-class>com.example.MyInterceptor</interceptor-class>
        </interceptor-binding>
    </assembly-descriptor>
</ejb-jar>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Does it work with a "ejb-name"-wildcard (*)?

Comment: I'll try, but even if it does, I only want the interceptor on this single bean.

Comment: Also, this example ejb-jar defines the interceptors first before binding them to an EJB: https://github.com/javaee-samples/javaee7-samples/blob/master/jms/send-receive/src/test/resources/WEB-INF/ejb-jar.xml (Sorry, currently I don't have the environment to try this out on the fly).

Comment: That's what I'm trying right now :)

Comment: No joy yet. It does not help.

Comment: Some people I also have seen are using the fully qualified name for the EJB instead of only the class name